# Intermediate level book for Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I've just completed an intro course and I'm looking for a text that will help teach intermediate level concepts.  ~susan~

Comment: welcome to StackOveflow Susan! :D

Comment: Do you mean a specific language supported by Visual Studio 2008 or really the IDE in general?

Comment: you are looking for Visual studio or ASP or C#?

Comment: Visual studio is an IDE. Are you looking help on IDE itself or on technologies that supported by VS ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a book, why not try [video training (www.vtc.com)](http://www.vtc.com/)? You can sample the languages in short bursts and pick a focus later. Search for "Visual" or just browse the programming category.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for, but have a look at the various online resources and tutorials, for example the different [developer centers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/default.aspx) or [http://asp.net](http://www.asp.net/) for everything related to web development.